# Using default Activity transition animation inside a view Group

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Is it possible to enable the default activity transition inside a view group.
Note that this effect can be achieved using a view transition which would replicate the default activity transition, however it turns out to be quite slow.

Any pointers on the same is appreciated. Thanks in advance.